# How can we download instagram stories with login in flutter?

Tags: flutter, download, instagram-api, instagram-story

I want to download instagram stories with login in flutter app.How can I do that ,using webview and parsing or any apis,If any one knows any resources?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [rapidapi](https://rapidapi.com/yuananf/api/instagram28/) Instagram api that's paid